# How to drop packets based on a probability with nftables?

Tags: linux, iptables, nftables

`iptables` has the [statistic module](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbCD) that allows doing operations on packets based on a probability, how would I go about and do this with nftables?

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a good question for those that want to migrate to nftables from iptables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### numgen

*nftables* has all features in place, but for some unknown reason, it's not documented in any version of the `nft` manpage.

The kernel side handling this, [*nft_numgen*](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/netfilter/nft_numgen.c) has been available [since Linux 4.9](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/net/netfilter/nft_numgen.c?h=v4.9-rc1&id=91dbc6be0a62d3bcea98287734d593610aed507d) and the userland side [since](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/src/numgen.c?id=13eeed6ea6f0a5d1353ee5ad14c4322695b4f59b) the [nftables 0.7 release](https://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter-devel/msg45557.html):

> - Add number generation support. Useful for round-robin packet mark setting, eg.
>
>   ```
>   # nft add rule filter prerouting meta mark set numgen inc mod 2
>   ```
>
>   You can also specify an offset to indicate from what value you want 
>     to start from.
>
>   The modulus provides the scale of the counting sequence. You can
>     also use this from maps, eg.
>
>   ```
>   # nft add rule nat prerouting \
>         dnat to numgen inc mod 2 map { 0 : 192.168.10.100, 1 : 192.168.20.200 }
>   ```
>
>   So this is distributing new connections in a round-robin fashion
>     between 192.168.10.100 and 192.168.20.200. Don't forget the special
>     NAT chain semantics: Only the first packet evaluates the rule,
>     follow up packets rely on conntrack to apply the NAT information.
>
>   You can also emulate flow distribution with different backend
>     weights   using intervals, eg.
>
>   ```
>   # nft add rule nat prerouting \
>         dnat to numgen inc mod 10 map { 0-5 : 192.168.10.100, 6-9 : 192.168.20.200 }
>   ```

There's also support for random numbers. Example: replacing in a previous example `inc` (used for round-robin) with `random`:

```
nft add rule nat prerouting dnat to numgen random mod 2 map { 0 : 192.168.10.100, 1 : 192.168.20.200 }
```

Further documentation and related stuff:

- [Math operations - Number generator - nftables wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Math_operations#Number_generator)
- [Load balancing - nftables wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Load_balancing)
- Initial presentation from the author of the *numgen* module at Netdev 1.2: [Load Balancing with nftables II (PDF)](https://netdevconf.org/1.2/slides/oct6/08_nftables_Load_Balancing_with_nftables_II_Slides.pdf)
- Load balancer using *nftables*: [*nftlb*](https://github.com/zevenet/nftlb) (from same person / company).

---

### Back to the question

The random number is a 32 bits integer (big enough to ignore modulus bias) on which is applied a modulus. Its value can then be compared. To drop 5% of all non-local incoming IPv4 packets that would then be:

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table ip filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
        iif "lo" accept
        numgen random mod 100 < 5 drop
    }
}
```

Example when pinging from its host a container with this ruleset:

```
# ping -q -f 10.0.3.66
PING 10.0.3.66 (10.0.3.66) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.0.3.66 ping statistics ---
34351 packets transmitted, 32592 received, 5% packet loss, time 19744ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.004/0.017/0.481/0.018 ms, ipg/ewma 0.574/0.017 ms
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I hope they'll add this module to the list of things `iptables-translate` can translate to save others the trouble when they're trying to simulate packet loss with nftables.